# Insert into table with primary key bound values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that consists of an integer primary key and 3 text strings.
I am want to be able to insert a new row by just specifying the 3 strings, **but** I want to use positional binding
e.g. `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?,?,?)` and the bind the values
When I try this the query fails with a parameter miscount.

Is this at all possible or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

as you are saying your table consists of primary key column and 3 text columns that means you have 4 columns in your table and when you are trying to insert you are not mentioning which columns you are using in your insert statement

you need to specify the column name (excluding primary key column) in your query like below.

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE> (text_column_1, text_column_2, text_column_3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```